# Video recording of IPhone screen of total game play

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, video-recording

I want to record screen video recording during application running and unfortunately apple didn't provide any scratch code on it.

The scenario is there a 'RECORD' button and a 'STOP' button. when I touch 'RECORD', I need to take a video of the entire gameplay (Screen Video) and stop recording when I touch 'STOP'. 
Is there any other method besides the screenshot method to do this?
For example - Talking Tom, Angry birds, etc.

Comment: I did this functionality using AVFoundation.framework classes

Answer (score 2):

Instead of taking a video, you could record the user interactions and replay them. If you use a PRNG for random events, you should also make sure to seed it with the same value while replaying a game.

Screen capture in iOS has a few problems, one of which being performance, and the other being the fact that some animations are not captured because they happen at some low level, out of sight for normal screen capturing methods.

This, of course, will only replay the game on screen.

Comment: i think in talking tom application doing smooth video recording of tom activities, so there may be any way to we can crack this question. At prior i also thinking to take screenshot and keep it in the queue and after that export it video in background, but it is not optimize solution for me.

Comment: no Tom is not recording video. it only process video once you want to save it to gallery or post it on social network.

Answer (score 0):

if we talk about angry birds, that has been developed in COCOS2D and if your game is also developed in cocos2d, you are lucky..!! Maybe if you dig-in you could find a way to use it with UIKit as well...who knows..!!

there is a cocos2d 3rd party utility named -Kamcord that can be used for recording gameplay.
[kamcord.com](http://kamcord.com/)

[COCOS2D Kamcord archive link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1942)

Answer (score 0):

We provide an SDK called "Everyplay" that allows you to do exactly what you're looking for. It's free to use, and is lightweight.

We provide out-of-the-box integrations for Unity3D, cocos2d (1.x, 2.x), cocos2d-x, and you can of course integrate to a custom OpenGL-based game engine.

The documentation is available at https://developers.everyplay.com/doc

The documentation contains an example app key to use when developing, but you can of course sign up for your own client key at https://developers.everyplay.com/